# How can I set up a completely separate (not multisite) Wordpress installation as a subdirectory of an existing Wordpress blog?

Tags: multisite, htaccess, directory, apache

I currently have a Wordpress multisite network running at `http://www.mysite.com` and rooted in `/var/www/html`. I need to set up a completely separate, single-site Wordpress installation accessible via `http://www.mysite.com/intranet` and rooted in `/var/www/html/vhosts/intranet/html`. It will use a separate database, a separate set of plugins and themes, etc.

I'm aware that this is not the best of ideas, but it's what the client wants. How can I achieve this setup?

Comment: The best I could manage was to point `http://www.mysite.com/intranet` to the child site's homepage ([here's the `.htaccess`](http://pastebin.com/BnmCstJV)). However, any links on it redirect to the parent site and so does `http://www.mysite.com/intranet/wp-admin`.

Comment: Ok. This is not too hard with a single site setup. I don't know how multisite might complicate it, but put your subdomain stuff first and thus avoid the multisite rules altogether.

Comment: [I must be doing something wrong here.](http://pastebin.com/82nKtQ1w) Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to move the child installation to the main site's web root, and rename its subdirectory to `intranet`. Once I had done this, all I had left to do was place this line of code after the main site's rules:

```
RewriteRule ^intranet/ - [L]
```

The `-` rewrites the URI to itself - thus overriding any previous rules. The request is then passed on to the child site as is.